# Execution of variable with Execute Immediate

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

When I am trying to run the below code getting error like "PL/SQL compilation error". What I did wrong in this ?

```
declare vsql varchar2(500);
 begin
   vsql:='begin
   create global temporary table temp_subset 
    ( id number
      ,"Category"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"Class"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"Measure"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"Actuals Year Total"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"COL NAME" varchar2(256)
      ,value varchar2(2048)
    );
end;';
execute immediate vsql;
end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating a table with dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vsql:='
   create global temporary table temp_subset 
    ( id number
      ,"Category"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"Class"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"Measure"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"Actuals Year Total"  varchar2(2048)
      ,"COL NAME" varchar2(256)
      ,value varchar2(2048)
    ) on commit delete rows';
```

---

If two tables are needed to be created:

```
vsql:='
  begin
    execute immediate ''create table t1 ()'';
    execute immediate ''create table t2 ()'';
  end;
';
```

Comment: Ok thanks, its working fine, if i want to execute two tables creation in single variable. How can we create that. Can you give me one example for this.